# Filtering array and display only filtered items

Tags: vue.js

I am working on my website which will have my CV.
So I have an array of objects with hard and soft skills

```
 skills: [
  { id: "1", type: "hard", title: "Technical skills" },
  { id: "2", type: "hard", title: "Computer skills" },
  { id: "3", type: "hard", title: "Microsoft Office skills" },
  { id: "4", type: "hard", title: "Analytical skills" },
  { id: "5", type: "hard", title: "Marketing skills" },
  { id: "6", type: "hard", title: "Presentation skills" },
  { id: "7", type: "hard", title: "Management skills" },
  { id: "8", type: "hard", title: "Project management skills" },
  { id: "9", type: "hard", title: "Writing skills" },
  { id: "10", type: "hard", title: "Language skills" },
  { id: "11", type: "hard", title: "Design skills" },
  { id: "12", type: "soft", title: "Leadership Skills" },
  { id: "13", type: "soft", title: "Teamwork" },
  { id: "14", type: "soft", title: "Communication Skills" },
  { id: "15", type: "soft", title: "Problem-Solving Skills" },
  { id: "16", type: "soft", title: "Work Ethic" },
  { id: "17", type: "soft", title: "Flexibility/Adaptability" },
  { id: "18", type: "soft", title: "Interpersonal Skills" },
],
```

And so I have two li's. So I need to display only hard skills in the first li and only soft skills in the second li.
Yes I know it'd be much easier if I just make 2 arrays and cycle through them for each one of li's, but I want to kinda challenge myself and filter the array. Obviously filter by the "type". So the return has to be an array, so I can cycle through it to display the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example use two `computed`:

```js
computed: {
  hardSkills() {
    return this.skills.filter(skill => skill.type === 'hard');
  },
  softSkills() {
    return this.skills.filter(skill => skill.type === 'soft');
  }
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks, works perfect. Could you please clarify something for me?
So I am creating a new computed property which filters an array, and then cycling through this computed property?

Comment: @MikeOxhuge Yes. In your Vue template your can use them like normal vars. (for example `<div v-for="skill in hardSkills"></div>`)

Comment: `<li v-for="hardSkill in hardSkills" :key="hardSkill.id">
        {{ hardSkill.title }}
      </li>`

In my case it's `hardSkill in hardSkills`
I checked and it didn't work with `skill in hardSkills`

Comment: `v-for="x in y"` means you store each items of `y` in the temporary variable `x`. The name of the var can be anything. You can write `foobar in hardSkills`, it still works when using `foobar.id`

Comment: `v-for="ball in hardSkills"
      :key="ball.id"`
it doesnt work that way. There's just empty field on the page when I change `hardSkill in hardSkills`  by `anything in hardSkills`

Answer (score 1):

You could create the 2 arrays with a simple [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this

```js
const hardSkills = skills.filter(skill => skill.type === 'hard')
const softSkills = skills.filter(skill => skill.type === 'soft')
```

Then, go to your template and loop on those in your template.

Comment: Thanks, but why const? And where shall I declare it? In `data () { return { const hardSkills = skills.filter(skill => skill.type === 'hard') }}`  or just in export? 
I think the computed property is easier.

Comment: No offense, but it seems you lack JavaScript very basics ;) You should probably start by learning JS before Vue.

Comment: Yes, @Byscripts, I do lack on JS basics. I tried to learn it and it was way too hard (perhaps I couldn't find any tutorial for beginners). So after learning what's a var, function, array and object I jumped to Vue. Because I could find a 'teacher' who explains things in a very easy and understandable way. Not sure if I am allowed to promote any YouTube channel over here, so I gonna take a risk and say: it is Shaun Net Ninja.

Comment: Check wes' bos beginner JS and practice with his JavaScript 30, great teacher but you will need to be pretty focus to follow.